# Why is my navigation menu not showing up?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website with some friends for fun and we are having an issue with the nav menu not showing up after we press the button, I had to use flexbox to align my hamburger menu to the navbar originally, but now when we press it, it isnt showing any of the sub menus at all.

Yes, we realize that webkit is for scss, it was just there for examples

```css
.topnav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.navbarItems a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.navbarItems a:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: black;
}
.navbarItems a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}
/* Hambuger Menu */
.burger {
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 4px solid currentColor;
  width: 28px;
  transition: border-top 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-top 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.burger::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.burger:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 4px solid currentColor;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.burger:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 4px solid currentColor;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
}

.burger-check {
  display: none;
}

.burger-check:checked ~ .burger {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  transition: border-top 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-top 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.burger-check:checked ~ .burger:before {
  transform: rotate(-405deg) translateY(1px) translateX(-3px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-405deg) translateY(1px) translateX(-3px);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  align-self: center;
}
.burger-check:checked ~ .burger:after {
  transform: rotate(405deg) translateY(-4px) translateX(-5px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg) translateY(-4px) translateX(-5px);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.burger-check:checked ~ .navigation{
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: purple;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

p {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: centeR;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.img {
  width:1000px;
  height:400px;
}

.header {
  width: 322px;
  height: 219px;
}
h4 {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: square;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <div class="navbarItems">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/about.php">About</a> 
</div>
</div>
 <input class="burger-check" id="burger-check" type="checkbox">
  <label for="burger-check" class="burger"></label>
  </div>
  <nav id="navigation1" class="navigation"> 
  <ul>
    <li><h1>Professional Awards</h1></li>
    <li><a href="Advisor Of The Year Award.php">Advisor of the Year Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Professional Awards/Emerging Advisor Of The Year Award.php">Emerging Advisor of the Year Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Professional Awards/Emerging Professional Of The Year Award.php">Emerging Professional of the Year Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Professional Awards/Hall Of Fame Award.php">Hall of Fame Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Professional Awards/Outstanding Service Award.php">Outstanding Service Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Professional Awards/Student Of The Year Award.php">Student of the Year</a></li>
    
    <li><h1>Service Learning Awards</h1></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Service Learning Awards/Community Service Award.php">Community Service Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Service Learning Awards/Environmental Action Awareness Award.php">Environmental Action Awareness</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Service Learning Awards/Safety Awareness Award.php">Safety Awareness Award</a></li>  
    <li><a href="/Pages/Service Learning Awards/Service Learning Individual Award.php">Service Learning Individual Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Service Learning Awards/Special Olympics Award.php">Special Olympics Award</a></li>
    
    <li><h1>Special Recognition Awards</h1></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Special Recognition Awards/BPA Marketing and Public Relations.php">BPA Marketing and Public Relations</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Special Recognition Awards/BPA Merit Scholar.php">BPA Merit Scholar</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Special Recognition Awards/Chapter Activities Award of Excellence.php">Chapter Activities Award of Excellence</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Special Recognition Awards/Membership Explosion Award.php">Membership Explosion Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Special Recognition Awards/Recruiter of the Year Award.php">Recruiter of the Year Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Special Recognition Awards/Social Media Award.php">Social Media Award</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Pages/Special Recognition Awards/The Professional Cup Award.php">The Professional Cup</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: this is tagged as `php` because...? and `web-deployment-project`??

Comment: Yeah not sure why honestly

Comment: Seems to be working when I click the lines at the top of the page. Granted, the burger needs some styling work.

Comment: Can you remove that topnav max-height? I think it may be the cause. I haven't actually tested out the code. But assuming that a restricted height prevents it from expanding

Comment: @showdev it's not showing up correctly through here for some reason. We are using cloud 9 to develop it and it's showing up but when we click it nothing shows up

Comment: It works in Chrome 63, Firefox 57 and Safari 11 on mac os. In which browser does it not show up?

Comment: That hamburger looks like it was run over by a truck. Is there a reason it's full width?